# CoreData - select specific entry from one to many relationship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

Damn you short titles! :p

Basically I have an entity named "threads" and I have an entity named "messages". I have a one to many relationship from threads ->> messages (and a one to one inverse relationship).

What I need to do is get all the records from the threads entity and for each one I need to get the message with the latest timestamp (this is just an int in the "lastUpdated" attribute, so the highest number I guess will suffice).

I'm not sure what other information you may want, here is a screenshot of my entities:

[image]

I'm sure there must be a better way than iterating through all the records and comparing the threadIds?

Thank you.

Comment: I've been meaning to do something like this in my own app but **somehow** keep forgetting to post here to ask.

Comment: Yeah, well normally I'd just compare the thread ids, but this project is based heavily on core data, so I thought I would put effort into learning how to make it efficient and learning everything about relationships and such. Can't find much information about core data anywhere though. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the individual Thread objects, you just need to do a sort on the Messages objects and take the topmost Message object.

The easiest solution would be to create a method in the Thread class like this:

```
- (Messages *) lastUpdatedMessage{
    NSSortDescriptor *sort=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastUpdated" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortedMessages=[self.messagesInThread sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    return [sortedMessages objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Then all you have to do is ask each Thread object for its lastUpdatedMessage.

A more complex but more efficient solution would be to create an intermediate linking entity that would link one Message object to one Thread object and set that link object as the Message objects update. So:

```
MessageThreadLink{
    message<--(required)-->Message.lastUpdateLink
    thread<--(required)-->Thread.lastUpdatedMessage
}
```

Whenever a Message object updated, it would tell it's related Thread object to delete the existing link object and create another one pointing to it. You would probably put that code in a custom setter for the lastUpdated property.

With this method you just have to ask each thread for its lastUpdatedMessage and it appears automatically without a lot of searching and sorting.

Comment: Best (any?) way to do this without pulling all the messages into memory and sorting them? Be nice to do the sort in the DB and then set a limit 1 to the query so you only get the one you want.  (Imagine 1M messages).  I'm guessing you'd have to change the model?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use [**NSPredicate**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) to perform a filter on the data and attributes values you need like you'd perform a query on a simple database?
(or maybe I'm missing a point)

Comment: I could do but then whats the point in relationships?! I would have thought there would be a way to access the entities through a relationship.

Comment: I guess you are misinterpreting relatiionships or I am misinterpreting you : ) Relationships are just an object oriented abstraction of what are _relationship_ in a data base conceptual model such as ER/EER so you can access the items that take part in the relationship via a collection (NSSet) and key path valuing. So the most efficient way is to let Core Data fetch you what you need by using a Predicate given a current data model. Maybe you can alter the data model as Rog suggests to get some more performance

Answer (score 0):

So your lastUpdated attribute is an int and not NSDate? If so, does it have to be an int and do you do anything else with the data stored in that attribute?

I was thinking you could possibly use a BOOL attribute that marks a message as lastUpdated == YES and then all you need to do is fetch your Message entities that match that predicate. You will still be able to access the thread entity via the one-to-one relationship so you can fetch and display that data the way you want.

[edit]
As a side note, I think you might find it more intuitive to use singular words to name your entities as each Thread entity contains one thread and each message entity contains one message.

**OR Option 2**

change your lastUpdated attribute to be NSDate and set the default value for NOW so whenever the entity is created it will pre-populate with the current date/time.

Then for each thread you have saved, pull the associated messages, sort them by NSDate and pick the first object on the array if ASCENDING == NO or the last object if ASCENDING == YES.

Comment: right, so you're saying that that (second option) would be the only way to do this? There's no way to do it using the relationships?

Comment: There might be other ways but no matter what you do you will have to fetch all messages that match a specific criteria - once that's done, you can then access their relationships to fetch the associated thread. Definitely more efficient than pulling and comparing all threadIds as originally suggested.